# Hard Drive got assigned letter F and boot fails

Tags: boot, ssd

I cloned a partition from my old drive and installed a new SSD in my laptop.  But now when I go to boot, after I log in, I get the message "preparing your desktop" which never finishes.  I have no start button, nothing.  Except that I can start task manager.  There I see that my hard drive is now assigned to F, not C and thus will not boot.  When I try to run diskpart to change the assignment, it says that diskpart cannot be found, even though I see it right there.

Any ideas?  I really do not want to start over with a clean install.

Thanks.

Windows 7, 64 bit

Comment: Solved.  Thanks for your help.  The first step was to figure out how to edit the registry on the boot drive while booting from the installation DVD.  I found that here:  http://4sysops.com/archives/regedit-as-offline-registry-editor/  The question of what edits to do was answered by gladiator2345 below and explained in his link.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your `PATH` variable to `PATH=%PATH%;[the path where you found diskpart.exe]` and then try again or navigate to the folder where you found diskpart.

You can also try diskmgmt.msc if it pops up and try change your drive letter from there by right clicking your drive and opting for "change drive letter and paths".

Comment: I don't understand why this is not working for me.  I can navigate to f:\windows\system32 and type a command that dir tells me is in that directory and an error message pops up saying that path does not exist -- even though I see it when I run dir.  setting the path does not help,  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Boot the laptop to the Windows 7 installation DVD. Then use the System Recovery options to launch a command prompt and run diskpart from there.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am still confused.  If I boot from the windows 7 installation DVD, then my HDD is already c:, so running diskpart does not change anything.  If I assign the HDD c: here, then boot into my HDD then it is still f: -- maybe because the registry on the HDD was not edited, only the registry loaded by the installation dvd.

Comment: Is there any way to edit the registry on a HDD when I have booted from a different drive?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the solution. Please see my question and answer here.

[Windows External Harddisk drive letter after cloning boot partition to it [Installing Windows in External drive]](https://superuser.com/questions/443800/windows-external-harddisk-drive-letter-after-cloning-boot-partition-to-it)

Press ctrl+alt+del to bring task manager then in run type regedit.

```
In registry navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices

Rename "\DosDevices\C:" to say "\DosDevices\B:"
```

Then rename "\DosDevices\D:" (where d: is the drive letter of windows installation in external usb.) to "\DosDevices\C:"