# TrueCrypt encrypted my hard drive and THEN warned that the drive letter will change

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, encryption, truecrypt

My laptop is broken, and I have to give it to a service tech soon. Unfortunately, I can not easily take off the hard drive with this model, it's deep inside. So I am frantically looking for ways to encrypt it instead.

So I found TrueCrypt, encrypted one of my 4 partitions, which took me 3 hours, and only then it warned me that I can't reuse the same drive letter. It is unclear, maybe it will let me reuse it if I delete my old partition letter in Windows, but I am not taking risks at this point unless I know for sure. I looked up for instructions on decrypting the same drive, and they are kind of complex; not to mention, they might take longer to execute than my computer can live.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to mount my new encrypted partition using the old drive letter?
2. If not, and I decrypt the drive, what alternative options are available to me? I'm using Windows 7 professional 64 bit. (BitLocker is not available with my version, right?)

Comment: What is laptop make/model?

Comment: @Ramhound, are you sure? That's not what I found out in my search. Could you please provide a link?

Comment: I would also add that you should back up all your data now - they'll likely just re-image the machine before they give it back to you (if they don't replace it entirely).

Comment: Cant you rename drive letters in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices . I have not tried it with encrypted drives and I am not sure if it helps. http://superuser.com/questions/443800/windows-external-harddisk-drive-letter-after-cloning-boot-partition-to-it-insta

Answer (score 0):

- Go to `Run`.
- Type in `compmgmt.msc` and press `Enter` to open `Microsoft Management Console` `/Computer Management`.
- Select  `Storage`.
- Select `Disk Management` and wait a second or two for it to initialize.
- Right-click on the drive who's letter you want to change.
- Click on `Change Drive Letters and Paths...`.
- In the window, select the drive again and click `Change...`
- Assign it the old letter such as *C* from the dropdown.
- Click `OK`.
- Click `OK` again.
- Voila.

This is supposed to work but as always, I chime in and jump in the bandwagon and say, "Please backup!".

Hope I could help! :)