# How to migrate a laptop Windows 10 boot partition to an external USB drive

Tags: windows, clone, migration, external-drive

Is it possible to clone (migrate) a laptop Windows 10 boot partition (no way to diconnect the drive) to an external USB drive and then boot Windows from the external drive?

I've looked over the following procedure and wonder if anyone was successful on Windows 10:

[Windows External Harddisk drive letter after cloning boot partition to it [Installing Windows in External drive]](https://superuser.com/questions/443800/windows-external-harddisk-drive-letter-after-cloning-boot-partition-to-it-insta)

Comment: Why would you want to do this, performance would be less than desirable.

Comment: I expect external SSD performance to be adequate as an archive partition.

Comment: Its still over usb....

Comment: I think USB 3.0 is fast enough to handle an external HD. Worst case scenario it will take longer to load Windows and applications.